# SQL server import wizard - how to skip bottom rows

Tags: sql-server

While using auto import wizard in SQL server 2014 we can skip top rows of the source file as required. But I also need to skip last few rows of the same file. How can this be achieved ?

For an example one of the column has all integer values. But on the last row of the same column has some text, which needs to be excluded. Otherwise I cannot import the column as INT.

Comment: You can specify a sql statement rather than a table transfer.

Comment: Hi Rhian, I am a beginner in SQL server. Can you let me know where I can see the sql statement of the current auto import wizard, so that i can make changes there?

Comment: what's the source file type?

Comment: how many rows do you have?

Comment: Number of rows might vary from file to file.

Comment: this is my solution....  import your flat file to a temptable in mssql make that specific column as varchar, once done filter out non numeric value on that column and move the rows to the official table....

Comment: use ISNUMERIC function to validate the data on that column... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms186272.aspx